# GeoCoordinateWatcher can't give live status or permission

Tags: windows-phone-7, location, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1

The whole purpose of what is trying to be accomplished is to update my program with the current enabled or disabled state of Locations service as set from the phone's setting page.

Normally you start an app and the GeoCoordinateWatcher grabs bot the status and permission just fine. The specific case I am noticing this failure is when you go to the settings page, and hold the back button and select my app directly. When my app comes back, it does not read the actual status of the Location services.

The Application_Activated and MainPage_OnNavigatedTo are both events I have that I can recheck the status and permission. At this point, no matter what I do, if I changed the setting while the app was killed, it shows the wrong information.

In those events, I have even spun up a new GeoCoordinateWatcher class and it still reports what the status and permission was when my app was last active.

What can I do to read the actual value, or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962%28v=vs.92%29.aspx),

> "This API, used for obtaining the geographic coordinates of the device, is supported for use in background agents, but it uses a cached location value instead of real-time data. The cached location value is updated by the device every 15 minutes."

It is quite possible you're getting the cached location after location services was disabled. 
What happens after, say an hour?

Comment: Do you see an alternate way of getting a realtime value?

Comment: Also, I am not using this in a background agent, so the documentation you quoted does not apply. The GeoCoordinateWatcher behaves differently in a background task so it does not consume unnecessary resources.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. I am not sure what the rules are regarding location updates to a re-activated app. I'll look to see if I can find anything.